# C program to break down input amount into bank notes

Tags: c, floating-point

I am working on an exercise to break down an amount of money in bank notes, but i am getting a floating point exception.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int amount, n100, n50, n20, n10, n5, n2, n1;

    printf("Input the amount: \n");
    scanf("%i", &amount);

    n100 = amount / 100;
    n50 = (amount % 100) / 50;
    n20 = (int)(n50 % (amount % 100)) / 20;
    n10 = (int)(n20 % (n50 % (amount % 100))) / 10;
    n5 = (int)(n10 % (n20 % (n50 % (amount % 100)))) / 5;
    n2 = (int)(n5 % (n10 % (n20 % (n50 % (amount % 100))))) / 2;
    n1 = (int)(n2 % (n5 % (n10 % (n20 % (n50 % (amount % 100)))))) / 1;
    
    printf("%i Note(s) of 100.00\n", n100);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 50.00\n", n50);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 20.00\n", n20);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 10.00\n", n10);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 5.00\n", n5);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 2.00\n", n2);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 1.00\n", n1);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `x % 0` is undefined, and you're likely to encounter a zero somewhere in that code.

Comment: You are dividing by 0 (most likely). Instead of doing complex math with modulos, you could subtract `n100 * 100` from `amount`, then `n50 * 50` etc.

Comment: Have you noticed that you're computing `amount % 100` no less than six times?

Comment: And you're doing a lot of casting from `int` to `int`, which is harmless but not useful.

Comment: DRY, forgot that

Comment: `n50` is either 0 or 1. Thus, `(n50 % (amount % 100))` is either 0 or 1 (when it is defined), and `(n50 % (amount % 100)) / 20` is always 0. You need to work some more on the arithmetic.

Comment: You don't use any floating point numbers there... You shouldn't be using the word floating point indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the DRY principle, how about using arrays for the the denominations and counts?

Whenever I see (e.g.) `v1, v2, v3, ..., vN` it "cries out" for an array.

For this use case, that may not be so obvious. But, it would be easier to see if N was a large number (e.g. 1000). That is, instead of 1000 *separate* variables, we have a single [array] variable that has 1000 elements in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COUNTOF(_arr)       (sizeof(_arr) / sizeof(_arr[0]))

int denoms[] = { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1 };
#define COUNT   COUNTOF(denoms)

int counts[COUNT];

int
main(void)
{
    int amount;

    printf("Input the amount: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d",&amount);

    int value = amount;
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < COUNT;  ++idx) {
        int denom = denoms[idx];
        counts[idx] = value / denom;
        value %= denom;
    }

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < COUNT;  ++idx) {
        int count = counts[idx];
        if (count)
            printf("%d Notes of %d.00\n",count,denoms[idx]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it looks great. 
You lost me with this one.
I have much to learn

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments on most amounts you will encounter a `x % 0` at some point which is undefined behavior and will throw an error.

A basic approach to improve your code could be like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int amount, n100, n50, n20, n10, n5, n2, n1;
    int rest;

    printf("Input the amount: \n");
    scanf("%i", &amount);

    n100 = amount / 100;
    rest = amount % 100;
    
    n50 = rest / 50;
    rest = rest % 50;
    
    n20 = rest / 20;
    rest = rest % 20;
    
    n10 = rest / 10;
    rest = rest % 10;
    
    n5 = rest / 5;
    rest = rest % 5;
    
    n2 = rest / 2;
    rest = rest % 2;
    
    n1 = rest;
    
    printf("%i Note(s) of 100.00\n", n100);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 50.00\n", n50);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 20.00\n", n20);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 10.00\n", n10);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 5.00\n", n5);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 2.00\n", n2);
    printf("%i Note(s) of 1.00\n", n1);

    return 0;   
}
```

This way you do a lot less casting, it is more clear what's happening and there is no chance of encountering zero divisions.

Answer (score -1):

There are two more ways in which this program can be written. In first method we use the humble *printf* function. In the second method we use *while* loops.

In the **first** method we use an integer variable '*d*' to scan the user input. To find how many bank notes of denomination 100 will be used we divide this variable with 100 and print the Quotient. Then we reassign '*d*' to be the Remainder when this variable is divided by 100 - using the Arithmetic Operator *%* modulus and combining it with the assignment operator '*=*'. The code d %= 100 can be read as d = d % 100. Similar pattern follows for notes of other denominations.

```
# include<stdio.h>

int main() {
int d;
printf("Enter the value : ");
scanf("%d", &d);

printf("\n%d notes of 100 ", d / 100); d %= 100;
printf("\n%d notes of 50 ", d / 50); d %= 50;
printf("\n%d notes of 20 ", d / 20); d %= 20;
printf("\n%d notes of 10 ", d / 10); d %= 10;
printf("\n%d notes of 5 ", d / 5); d %= 5;
printf("\n%d notes of 2 ", d / 2); d %= 2;
printf("\n%d notes of 1 ", d / 1); d %= 1;

return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Enter the value : 188

1 notes of 100
1 notes of 50
1 notes of 20
1 notes of 10
1 notes of 5
1 notes of 2
1 notes of 1
```

Moving to the **second** method we can rewrite this code using *while* loops as:

```
# include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a, b;
    
    printf("Enter the value : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    b = 0;
    while (a >= 100) {
        a -= 100; 
        b += 1;
    } printf("\n%d notes of 100", b);
    
    b = 0;
    while (a >= 50) {
        a -= 50; 
        b += 1;
    } printf("\n%d notes of 50", b);

    b = 0;
    while (a >= 20) {
        a -= 20; 
        b += 1;
    } printf("\n%d notes of 20", b);

    b = 0;
    while (a >= 10) {
        a -= 10; 
        b += 1;
    } printf("\n%d notes of 10", b);
   
    b = 0;
    while (a >= 5) {
        a -= 5; 
        b += 1;
    } 
    printf("\n%d notes of 5", b);
    
    b = 0;
    while (a >= 2) {
        a -= 2; 
        b += 1;
    } 
    printf("\n%d notes of 2", b);
    
    b = 0;
    while (a >= 1) {
        a -= 1; 
        b += 1;
    } 
    printf("\n%d notes of 1", b);

    return 0;

}
```

Here we use integer variable '*a*' to scan user input. To calculate how many notes of denomination are used we use a counting variable'*b*' in a while loop. For notes having denomination 100 we subtract the user input with 100 on loop till the value is greater than or equal to 100 - simultaneously increasing the value of the counter. As the loop exits value of '*a*' is reduced by the looped subtractions. Then we reset the counter '*b*' to '*0*'.

The output of this code is:

```
Enter the value : 387

3 notes of 100
1 notes of 50
1 notes of 20
1 notes of 10
1 notes of 5
1 notes of 2
0 notes of 1
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. I will be posting this solution on other platforms as well including but not limited to geeksforgeeks.